# Insert "Click for Availability" on Magento Catalog Pages

Tags: magento, web, magento-1.7, visual-web-developer

In Magento 1.7, when you click on a category, and the product catalog for that category comes up, I would like to add the words "Click for Availability" next to or below each item.  Can someone please let me know how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

The file you need to edit is

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

But editing that file directly is not upgrade-safe, so you'll need to move it to

```
/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

That will override the `base` file automatically. Note that there are two view modes--grid and list, both of which are indicated by a comment in the list.phtml file--so be sure to edit both for your change to be visible at all times.

It looks like you'll want to add your line inside the product `<li>` for grid view, which is line 94 for me. For list view, you should put it inside the the `.product-shop` div, which is line 52. It's hard to be more specific without knowing exactly what you have in mind. You'll just need to play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

In list.phtml add a button "Check Availability" which on click triggers a JavaScript function

pass this to the function

```
$_product->isSaleable()
```

if this is true show in a div Available else not Available

This availability code is already checked in magento